# Should questions tagged [sprinkler-system] and/or [turf] be migrated to Gardening & Landscaping?

Tags: discussion, migration

We currently have 17 questions tagged [sprinkler-system](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sprinkler-system).

We also have 4 questions tagged [turf](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turf) (though there is some overlap)

Should these be candidates for migration to Gardening & Landscaping?

Should we make these questions off topic? Or could they exist on either site?

Answer (score 4):

The [sprinkler-system](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sprinkler-system) tag on the [Gardening and Landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) site has only one question, and I couldn't find a “sod” tag there. I think we should wait to migrate until the gardening site has more questions than we do on the topic of the question. Or at least until there is evidence that the questions are on topic on the gardening site, and that the gardening site has a substantial group of people who cares about the topics.

Comment: It's been pointed out that a better term for [sod] would be [turf] - I might retag these 4 questions and then see

Answer (score 0):

Another example of SE perhaps becoming *too* segregated. ;)

If there is a SE site specifically labeled 'landscaping' then I suppose any landscaping questions should go there.

Unless both SE sites are extremely busy (and I don't think they are) perhaps they should be combined into a 'Home and Garden'?